# How do I download a magnet link in ctorrent?

Tags: linux, magnet-links

Enhanced [ctorrent](http://www.rahul.net/dholmes/ctorrent/) apparently supports magnet links. How do I download from a magnet link using ctorrent?

Comment: @Mark Ctorrent is a console-based torrent client.

Comment: What distro are you on?

Comment: @nerdwaller: How exactly is that related?

Comment: If there was a tweak to get it going (a lib or otherwise), I wanted to provide the full details to get it installed. The intention is so that people searching this in the future could translate it to their specific situation. Sorry for being ambiguous in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the list of features and the changelog of enhanced ctorrent, I notice a complete absence of magnet links or any mention there of.

You may want to look at Transmission.

Comment: Ended up using Deluge.